# Is there a reasonable replacement for overloading and perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

If I accept a value by copy/move and then perform a move on it, it seems to copy LValues and move RValues.

Will this code perform correctly and efficiently for both cases?

Is it a reasonable alternative to creating  RValue and LValue overloads for useA2(), or for turning the useA2 function into a template to use forwarding?

```
struct A
{
    int *buff;
    A() { cout << "A::constructor\n"; buff = new int[1000]; } //expensive 
    A(const A& a) { cout << "A::copy constructor\n";   buff = new int[1000]; memcpy(buff, a.buff, 1000); }
    A(A&& a) { cout << "A::move constructor\n";   buff = a.buff; a.buff = nullptr; }
    ~A() { cout << "A::destructor\n"; delete buff; }
};


A getA()
{
    A temp;  // without temp, compiler can perform copy elision, skipping copy/move constructors
    return temp;
}


void useA2(A a)
{
    A a1 = std::move(a);
}


void demo()
{
    A a1;
    //useA2(getA());  // performs 2 moves
    useA2(a1);   // performs a copy to the input param, then moves the copy 

}
```

Comment: `getA` doesn't perform any copy/move due to RVO.

Comment: @ALX23z Technically, this is NRVO and it's not mandatory even in C++17. Most compilers, however, apply it by default.

Comment: I would only provide `void useA2(A&& a)` and let caller makes the copy: `useA2(A(a1))` if I want to control copy.

Answer (score 2):

Likely the most generic and efficient solution is to use **perfect forwarding**:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void useA2(Ts&&... vs)
{
   A a1 { std::forward<Ts>(vs)... };
}
```

Then, `useA2(a1);` will just invoke one copy constructor without any unnecessary moves.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, when I first posted the question i wrote "reasonable replacement for overloading or using std::forward", but then edited it to simplify the question.